# Написание новых man-страниц

Tags: debian, локализация, man

В `/usr/share/man/man1/` находятся мануалы для программ с расширением gz. Внутри этих gz архивов html (если верить команде `file /usr/share/man/man1/ab.1`) документ с похожим содержанием: (

```
.\" XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
.\" DO NOT EDIT! Generated from XML source.
.\" XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
.de Sh \" Subsection
.br
.if t .Sp
.ne 5
.PP
\fB\\$1\fR
.PP
..
.de Sp \" Vertical space (when we can't use .PP)
.if t .sp .5v
.if n .sp
..
.de Ip \" List item
.br
.ie \\n(.$>=3 .ne \\$3
.el .ne 3
.IP "\\$1" \\$2
..
.TH "AB" 1 "2015-05-01" "Apache HTTP Server" "ab"

.SH NAME
ab \- Apache HTTP server benchmarking tool
```

Вопросы:

1. Это чистый html ?
2. Как добавить дополнительную локализацию,чтобы сохранился оригинал.Т.е переведённый файл нужно будет добавить в этот же gz архив или создавать для новой локализации отдельный gz архив в отдельной папке `/usr/share/man/ru/man1/локализация_для_проги.gz` ?
3. Что означает конечная цифра 1 в названии файла ? При локализации ab.1 мне нужно будет изменить его на ab.2 ?

Comment: Ничего себе html o_O Да даже не похож...

Comment: Нажми Ctrl+U на этой странице и посмотри, как выглядит html :)

Comment: Повод отправить баг-репорт по программе file :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Это чистый html ?

**Нет**, это даже не язык разметки. [это plain-text, разбавленный командами форматирования roff](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roff). когда-то программа, понимающая это форматирование, и способная оформить текст в каком-нибудь другом формате, называлась runoff, потом пошли наследники — troff, nroff, [groff](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roff). (доп. см. `$ man 7 man`)

> Как добавить дополнительную локализацию,чтобы сохранился оригинал.Т.е переведённый файл нужно будет добавить в этот же gz архив или создавать для новой локализации отдельный gz архив в отдельной папке `/usr/share/man/ru/man1/локализация_для_проги.gz`?

**Да**, [локализованные man-страницы надо помещать в каталоги, называющиеся по имени языка локализации](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-docs.html#s12.1). каталоги должны располагаться на том же уровне иерархии, что и каталоги для *секций* (см. следующий ответ), и тоже должны быть разбиты на под-каталоги с секциями (`man1`, `man2` и т.д.). т.е., путь должен звучать примерно как: `/usr/share/man/ru/man1/программа.1` (или `/usr/share/man/ru/man1/программа.1.gz`, если файл сжат программой gzip)

> Что означает конечная цифра 1 в названии файла?

Это номер секции. цитата из `$ man 1 man`:

```
1   Executable programs or shell commands
2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
6   Games
7   Miscellaneous (including macro packages and conventions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
```

Для примера: `$ man 1 man` — это запуск программы *man* с передачей ей двух параметров — номера секции (`1`) и названия запрашиваемой страницы (`man`). номера секций фигурируют не только в именах каталогов, но и в именах файлов (предполагаю, что последнее — это просто дань традиции или «тяжёлое наследие»)

> При локализации `ab.1` мне нужно будет изменить его на `ab.2`?

**Нет**, переименовывать не надо. Разве что файл по смыслу должен принадлежать секции 2 и размещаться каталоге `ru/man2` (см. предыдущий ответ).